# Google Chart: How to change option for dynamic length of series

Tags: google-visualization, json.net

There is data for google chart in JSON format from server and I instantiate Google Chart DataTable like this

```
var google_graph = new google.visualization.DataTable(json_data_from_server);
```

Then I set options for the chart, ComboChart(Bar + Line). I try to set the last series(number 11) to line chart but the number of series changes based on  query.

```
var options = {
    title: 'Combo Chart',
    seriesType: "bars",
    series: {                                
        11: {
            type: 'line',                                                                        
        }
    }
};
```

Is there other way something like code below?

```
var options = {
    title: 'Combo Chart',
    seriesType: "bars",
    series: {                                
        getNumberOfColumns(): {
            type: 'line',                                                                        
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing:

```
var last = google_graph.getNumberOfColumns() -1; // if it doesn't work, change -1 to -2

var options = {
    title: 'Combo Chart',
    seriesType: "bars",
    series: {                       

        }
    }
};

options.series[last]={type:''line'}
```